# pactl can't unremap monitor source

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, pipewire

**Background:**

I have a monitor with aux in and out.
When trying to use some applications I couldn't use the monitor device, so I tried remapping it to a normal pulse audio source. Unfortunately, I misunderstood the command syntax and somehow made the monitor source monitor the audio output instead of the mic.

**The problem:**

I ran

```bash
pactl load-module module-remap-source master=alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor source_name=alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1 source_properties=device.description="display-mic"
```

Instead of

```bash
pactl load-module module-remap-source master=alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor source_name=display-mic source_properties=device.description="display-mic"
```

And now I have made a loopback from `hdmi-stereo-extra1` to `hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor`.

**What I have tried:**

I have removed the audio configs in my home directory.
Checked configs in /etc and friends.
Ran different pactl commands to try and revert the change.
Reset all the configs with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" pipewire pipewire-pulse  pipewire-audio pipewire-bin  pipewire-alsa alsa-tools alsa-utils pulseaudio-utils
```

**Debug info:**

Before anyone asks yes I did have mic input before this.

I am running Debian 11, with Gnome which uses `pipewire` and `pipewire-pulse` for pulse compatibility.

```
#arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pipewire
    PipeWire Sound Server
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=2
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=2
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Front output / input
dsnoop:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Generic,DEV=2
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
```

```
#aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pipewire
    PipeWire Sound Server
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, MB16AWP
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, MB16AWP
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, MB16AWP
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, MB16AWP
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
```

```
#pactl list cards
Card #40
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_07_00.1
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA NVidia at 0xfc080000 irq 101"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HDA NVidia"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:07:00.1"
        device.description = "High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_07_00.1"
        device.nick = "HDA NVidia"
        device.plugged.usec = "4836303"
        device.product.id = "0x0be3"
        device.product.name = "High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "34"
        object.id = "40"
        object.serial = "40"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfc080000 irq 101"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.string = "0"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:hdmi-stereo-extra1
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "1"
                device.product.name = "MB16AWP"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "3"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3
```